# Redirect all wlan0 request to webserver

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables, captive-portal

Usecase:

1. Whenever any wireless device will get connect to access point, it will send DHCP request. Access Point will forward DHCP request to Fortinet DHCP server and block all other request for that client. Fortinet DHCP server will assign IP address to wireless device.
2. Access Point will redirect client to local Terms & Condition page which is hosted by web server and wait until client accepts it.
3. When client accept the T&C, Access point will give internet access.

NOTE:

1. Access point will have hostapd to configure wireless access point.
2. Access point will have eth2388 vlan and all internet traffic will route through it.
3. Access point will host T&C webpage in its local server (Apache, thttpd)
4. On access point, no interface (eth0.2388, wlan0, brvl2388) should have ip due to security reasons
5. Fortinet dhcp server will also have internet access through eth0.2388 so clinet will access internet

-----This is what I did till now -----

--> Created a bridge brvl2388 by adding 2 interface eth0.2388 and wlan0. None of interface or bridge willb have ip due to security reasons.

--> Run hostapd by giving interface as wlan0 and creating the Access point named HOTSPOT

```
#hostapd.conf

interface=wlan0
ssid=HOSTSPOT
hw_mode=g
channel=6 
ieee80211n=1 
wpa=1
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

By doing this I assured client device got ip in dhcp range and have internet.

--> Now I want to run a webserver, which host index.html and whenever client connect to HOSTSPOT, he/she should redirect to index.html.

--> I have tried covachilli setup by disable the radius server from its conf. But the issue is covachilli runs it own dhcp server and client get ip of chilli's range i.e 10.1.0.2 series. I want client to get ip from external DHCP server.

--> I have also tried some iptables commands but not get sucess.

So, how to redirect all wlan0 request to webserver?

Comment: Um, what's the question?

Comment: This sounds more like someone's client requirements that you are trying to push on a volunteer community.